# Why isn't SaveChangesAsync actually saving all of my changes?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, entity-framework-6

I think I may be missing something in my understanding of how this is supposed to work. I have some code that imports a file. It loops through each record, does some processing, then adds that record to a table via a `DbContext` instance.

I initialize `DbContext` like this:

```
protected void ResetDbContext()
{
    if (_db != null)
        _db.Dispose();

    _db = new AppDBEntities();
    _db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    _db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
}
```

My main loop looks something like this:

```
foreach (var rec in engine)
{
    var record = new CommonImportRecord(rec);
    ProcessRecord(record, options, index);
    index++;
}

_db.SaveChanges();
```

`ProcessRecord` looks something like this:

```
protected async Task<int> ProcessRecord(CommonImportRecord record, ImportOptions options, int index)
{
    DisplayProcessStatus(index, options);
    // Code removed which fills in various properties of the record
    _db.MyTable.Add(record);
    if (index % options.UpdateInterval == 0)
    {
        return await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        // This was originally here, commented out when I changed SaveChanges() to SaveChangesAsync()
        // ResetDBContext();
    }
}
```

The only real changes I made for `SaveChangesAsync()` was to add `async Task<int>` as the return type of `ProcessRecord`, changed `SaveChanges()` to `return await SaveChangesAsync()` and commented out the call to `ResetDBContext.`

Things worked as expected before the async changes. Afterwards, it doesn't appear that all of my records are being saved.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are calling an `async` method which returns a task without waiting for it to complete. You need to use `await` to **asynchronously** wait before moving on to the next record. It's also a standard to name your `async` methods with the "Async" suffix:

```
foreach (var rec in engine)
{
    var record = new CommonImportRecord(rec);
    var result = await ProcessRecordAsync(record, options, index);
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to @l3arnon's answer, you can save yourself the generating of a state machine inside `ProcessRecordAsync`:

This:

```
protected async Task<int> ProcessRecordAsync(CommonImportRecord record, ImportOptions options, int index)
{
    // Removed code for brevity 
    return await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Can be turned into:

```
protected Task<int> ProcessRecordAsync(CommonImportRecord record, ImportOptions options, int index)
{
    // Removed code for brevity 
    return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

As you're not really using the return value of `SaveChangesAsync` inside the call to `ProcessRecordAsync`.